# Wrap a verbatim table environmet

Tags: tables, formatting, verbatim

I have text with all sorts of characters in it that I want to use in a table so
thought that verbatim might be suitable, but this doesn't seem to wrap. I've
seen suggestions for listings but this picks up certain characters.

Say the text is something such as -

```
  C_n = {(z_1, ..., z_n) \in R^n : z_i \neq z_j \forall i \neq j}. I want to
  prove that pi_k(C_n) = 1 \forall k > 1. any ideas?
```

Or such - so there are a real mix of characters in it.

It's also on multiple lines in my editor - so I don't want the formatting in the
TeX file to dictate the formatting that's done on screen.

It seems like there should be some kind of environment for this used like
`{\large <stuff>}` is, but I cant find one and don't know how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\raggedright

\texttt{\detokenize{C_n = {(z_1, ..., z_n) \in R^n : z_i \neq z_j \forall i \neq j}. I want to 
prove that pi_k(C_n) = 1 \forall k > 1. any ideas?}}

\end{document}
```